# JS script to calculates sum of amount calculates wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have prepared [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1gtrz3x/) that ilustrates how my script calculate twice the sum of each selected option attribute price. Please help me to solve this issue.

`optionsamount` is wrong, I mean is calculated twice.. Why is that? Thanks

```
function update_amounts(){
    var sum = 0.0;
    var optionsamount = 0.0;

    $('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function() {

        $('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function(){
            optprice = $(this).attr('price');
            optionsamount+= parseFloat(optprice);    
        })

        var qty = $(this).find('.qty option:selected').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty*price);
        sum+= (amount + optionsamount);

        $(this).find('.amount').text(''+ amount.toFixed(2));
    });

    $('.total').text(sum);
}
```

Comment: in the fiddle you never call the function `update_amounts()`

Comment: thats not the point I believe :)

Comment: Yeah, the fiddle is pretty useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
function update_amounts(){
var sum = 0.0;

$('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function() {

    var optionsamount = 0.0;


    $(this).find('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function(){
        optprice = $(this).attr('price');
        optionsamount+= parseFloat(optprice);    
    })

    var qty = $(this).find('.qty option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var amount = (qty*price);
    sum+= (amount + optionsamount);

    $(this).find('.amount').text(''+ amount.toFixed(2));
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```

Comment: Vaivhav, looks like you are the man ! :) big thank you ! What was wrong mate?

Comment: jquery selector ('.selectedoptionselect option:selected') was running each time for all products ...

Comment: Once again Thank you  Vaibhav !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function update_amounts(){
var sum = 0.0;

$('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function() {

    var optionsamount = 0.0;


    $('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function(){
        optprice = $(this).attr('price');
        optionsamount+= parseFloat(optprice);    
    })

    var qty = $(this).find('.qty option:selected').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var amount = (qty*price);
    sum+= (amount + optionsamount);

    $(this).find('.amount').text(''+ amount.toFixed(2));
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```

}

Comment: Alex it still calculates double optionsamount